# Panopoly with no views

Tags: views, distributions

I've just installed Panopoly 1.14 and I can't add views to my panels.

I create the view block normally without any problem; I can see the view, inside the block section, but when I try to create or edit the panel, I can't see views at all in the left side of the add-content screen where it should be.

I checked the permissions and I have all the administrative ones. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Go to admin/structure/panels/settings and check *Make all views available as panes*.